# Python MySql looping used up system resources

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have this for-loop that uploads csv files' data into sql tables, it runs smoothly for the first 10+ tables and after that the system is not responsive at all.

```
for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(dest_folder):
    for file in files:
        symbol = file.replace('.csv','')
        file_path = path.join(dest_folder, file)
        try:
            tp = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['Date'], date_parser=dateparse, header=0, index_col=None, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
            df = pd.concat(tp, ignore_index=True)

            df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

            engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://'+user+':'+password+'@'+host+':'+str(port)+'/'+dbname)
            tablename = 's_'+ symbol
            df.to_sql(
                name = tablename,
                con = engine,
                index = True,
                index_label='Id',
                chunksize=500,
                if_exists='append',
                dtype={
                    "symbol": String(20),
                    "Date": DateTime
                }
            )
            engine.dispose()
            del [[tp,df,engine]]
            gc.collect()
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to save csv data for %s' % (symbol))
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the following improved the slowness problem!!

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(engine, 'before_cursor_execute')
def receive_before_cursor_execute(conn, cursor, statement, params, context, executemany):
    if executemany:
        cursor.fast_executemany = True
```